# How to make an if statement do something if a String contains a searched text

Tags: javascript, string

I want to be able to do this:

```
var input1 = prompt("INPUT:");
if(input1 === "run"){
alert("You cannot do that");
}
```

On the prompt lets say you enter "run taco" How would I make the if statement activate if only part of it matched the string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use a regular expression:

```
if (/run/.test(input1)) {
```

or the `indexOf` function:

```
if (input.indexOf("run")!==-1) {
```

Comment: Or the simpler `if (input1.contains('run')) { ... }` (ES6 addition).

Comment: little extra to this answer. i use this style, little more readable to me,  i for case insensitive  whatever.search(new RegExp(value, 'i'; )) >= 0;

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.indexOf >= 0`

```
var input1 = prompt("INPUT:");
if(input1.indexOf("run") >= 0){
  alert("You cannot do that");
}
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript [**String.prototype**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/prototype) gives you several methods for this:

1. **[String.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)**:

> The **includes()** method determines whether one string may be found
>   within another string.
>
> Returns true or false as appropriate.

```
if (input.includes("run")) {
```

2. [**String.prototype.indexOf()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf):

> The **indexOf()** method returns the index within the calling String object of the first occurrence of the specified value, starting the search at fromIndex.
>
> Returns -1 if the value is not found.

```
if (input.indexOf("run")>-1) {
```

3. **[String.prototype.search()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search)**:

> The **search()** method executes a search for a match between a regular expression and this String object.
>
> Returns -1 if there's no match found.

```
if (input.search("run")>-1) {
```

4. **[String.prototype.match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)**

> The **match()** method retrieves the matches when matching a string against a regular expression.
>
> Returns an Array containing the matched results or null if there were no matches.

```
if (input.match("run").length>0) {
```